# Delete actor in UnrealScript from Python

Tags: python-3.x, unrealscript, unreal-engine5

I try to delete some actors in the scene using python but keep getting errors, I don't know how to modify my code.

**The error is generated in the second sentence:**

get_editor_subsystem() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

**Here is my code:**

```
path=“Test.thisIsTest”
unrealSystem=unreal.get_editor_subsystem()
delete_actor=unrealSystem.get_actor_reference(path)
unreal.EditorActorSubsystem.destroy_actor(delete_actor)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the Subsystem type in line 2:

```py
unreal.get_editor_subsystem(unreal.EditorActorSubsystem)
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another way:

```
editorActorSubsys = unreal.EditorActorSubsystem()
editorActorSubsys.destroy_actor(delete_actor)
```